# Производительность yield в nodejs, на сколько хорошо его использовать в основе проекта?

Tags: node.js, yield

Представим, что в проекте есть класс через который выполняется работа с бд во всем проекте, т.е. все модели наследуют его. И дабы сделать код "псевдо-асинхронным", избавиться от лишних коллбэков, есть вариант использовать `yield`. Но вопрос в том на сколько это правильно, со всех точек зрения, в т.ч. и с точки зрения производительности?

Например, на сколько лучше или хуже делать так:

```
let row = yield data.getRowById(id); //обращение к БД
```

чем так:

```
data.getRowById(id,(data) =>{ 
   let row = data;
});
```

Ну и одно дело использовать где-то в одном месте, а другое - использовать повсеместно в проекте где это возможно вместо коллбеков. Не столкнусь ли я с чем-то плохим?